# Flutter asset image wont display properly

Tags: flutter, dart, card, flutter-assetimage

I want to add an icon to a card widget so I used the ImageIcon widget as below

```
Card(
  color: colorPalette.cultured,
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(label,style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,fontSize: 15.0,fontFamily: 'Poppins'),),
        Spacer(),
        ImageIcon(AssetImage('assets/icons/call.png'),),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

The icon I want to display is,

[image: call.png]

but what is displayed is,

[image]

the assets in the pubspec.yaml are indented properly as well.

Comment: are there any error logs in the console

Comment: What happens if you remove the color palette ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of these for using asset images 
Image.asset('image')
or
Image(image: AssetImage('image')) for using asset images

For achieving it with icon

```
Container(
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                color: Colors.blue),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.call,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code Hope its help to you . Just change your image on your need

you have add asset image in 2 Ways

> 1. Image.assets() - Documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.asset.html)

> 2. AssetImage()

```
      Row(
             children: [
               Image(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/shop.png'),
                  width: 150,
                  height: 150,
                ),
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/cycle.png',
                  width: 150,
                  height: 150,
                ),
             ],
           ),
```

Your Result Screen -> [image]